# How to stop scroll movement when i click an item in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am using the following code to create a scrolling div in ASP.NET web application.

```
<div id="my_scroll_form" style="overflow:auto; height:500px">
    //My large form goes here (contains radio buttons and check boxes)
</div>
```

But whenever i scroll down and click on any radio button or checkbox, the scroll goes to top and i have to again scroll down. This happens every time i click on something on the form. Is there a way to stop that and not move the scroll to default top position whenever i interact with the form?

```html
<div id="request_scroll" style="overflow:auto; height:100px">
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option1" /> Option 1 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option2" /> Option 2 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option3" /> Option 3 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option4" /> Option 4 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option5" /> Option 5 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option6" /> Option 6 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option7" /> Option 7 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option8" /> Option 8 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option9" /> Option 9 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="option10" /> Option 10 <br />
</div>
```

The above is a working snippet in HTML but here the scroll wont reset if i click radio button. In my case im using ASP.NET web form with `<asp:RadioButtonList>` and my back end code is C# that handles `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event for this radiobutton list..Here when i click radio button in ASP.NET form the scroll resets to top position.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can prevent the click by using javascript [Event Preventdefault](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score -1):

Use this Code.

`Javascript` Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var div = document.getElementById("request_scroll");
            var div_position = document.getElementById("div_position");
            var position = parseInt('<%=Request.Form["div_position"] %>');
            if (isNaN(position)) {
                 position = 0;
            }
            div.scrollTop = position;
            div.onscroll = function () {
            div_position.value = div.scrollTop;
        };
        };
</script>
```

`Asp.Net` Code :

```
<div id="my_scroll_form" style="overflow:auto; height:500px;text-align:center">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <div id="request_scroll" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:100px;">

                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio1" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" /><br />
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio2" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged"/><br />
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton8" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio3" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton8_CheckedChanged"/><br />
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton7" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio4" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton7_CheckedChanged"/><br />
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton6" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio5" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton6_CheckedChanged"/><br />
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton5" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio6" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton5_CheckedChanged"/><br />
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton9" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio7" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton9_CheckedChanged"/><br />
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio8" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton4_CheckedChanged"/><br />
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio9" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton3_CheckedChanged"/><br />
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton10" runat="server" GroupName="lbl" Text="radio10" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton10_CheckedChanged"/><br />           

             </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="div_position" name="div_position" />
```